# Do different Retention Policies (RP) behave like tables when Querying with Flux?

Tags: influxdb, flux, influxdb-2

I would like to query the same measurement across different retention policies into a single graph. Ideally, I'd like to do this in the query itself, as I'm working with Grafana.

According to Flux documentation, "Flux structures all data in tables. When data is streamed from data sources, Flux formats it as annotated comma-separated values (CSV), representing tables. Functions then manipulate or process them and output new tables."

Would different retention policies behave like different tables in this context? Would I be able to use the union() function in order to get what I want? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So for something like this, you would just use two different `from` statements and use `union` or `join` to combine them. Check out the docs on `union` for a query example: https://v2.docs.influxdata.com/v2.0/reference/flux/stdlib/built-in/transformations/union/#examples

```
left = from(bucket: "database1/policy1")
  |> range(start: 2018-05-22T19:53:00Z, stop: 2018-05-22T19:53:50Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>
    r._field == "usage_guest" or
    r._field == "usage_guest_nice"
  )
  |> drop(columns: ["_start", "_stop"])

right = from(bucket: "database1/policy2")
  |> range(start: 2018-05-22T19:53:50Z, stop: 2018-05-22T19:54:20Z)
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>
    r._field == "usage_guest" or
    r._field == "usage_idle"
  )
  |> drop(columns: ["_start", "_stop"])

union(tables: [left, right])
```

In this case, the `bucket` used in the `from` function would be in the form of `database_name/rp`. See the docs on bucket naming conventions in 1.x: https://docs.influxdata.com/flux/v0.50/introduction/getting-started/#buckets